# What does "showrunner" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "showrunner" mean? How are they different from a producer or director? A showrunner doesn't replace them but the functions are similar, judging from the Lexico [definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/showrunner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Showrunner" is specifically a TV word, it isn't generally used for films or plays.

A showrunner has overall creative and managerial oversight for a TV series.  Individual episodes may have different writers, director, or even producers. The showrunner is above the directors of individual episodes, and ensures consistency or creative vision, and the fair distribution of resources across a series.

It is a modern term.  In older TV shows, the showrunner would be credited as "Executive Producer", and on British shows just as "Producer".  However a showrunner tends to have more creative input than a producer would typically have had.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me more like the "Line producer." The "Executive Producer" may have overall control, but the LP is right there handling the "day-to-day" details to make EVERY episode work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/136169)